# Retrofit java.net.UnknownHostException but the URL is valid

Tags: java, android, exception, retrofit

I'm using retrofit to fetch some data from my API, but I get the exception below. the URL is fine since it works from my browser

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: http:/192.168.0.105:81/service.asmx?op=readAll
```

Comment: Should it not be http:// instead of http:/  or is it just a typo

Comment: If the solution presented by @Rasmus doesn't solve it, try looking at your browser's proxy settings.

Comment: @Rasmus yes that was my problem thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL should be `http://` instead of `http:/`