# UnknownHostException after Android 11 update

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, galaxy, android-11

**Problem: Once an UnknownHostException is returned, the user continues to receive the same error unless the app is reinstalled or the device is rebooted.**

Of the users whose OS is Android 11, only a few users are having problems.

The biggest problem is that when an error occurs, the same error is returned continuously for each request.

According to users It is said that re-installing the app or rebooting the device will work again.

It seems that 99% are users of Samsung devices. Sometimes there are also Google Pixel phones.

Both Http and Https give the same error.

Both Wifi, 5G and LTE give the same error.

The request method is using POST and I don't know if it happens to GET as well, I don't use GET.

Also, either Thread is Background or Foreground, or both.

In this my code

**Gradle:**

```
android {
    minSdkVersion 21
    
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    /* RETROFIT */
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0'

    /* OKHTTP */
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.9.0'

    /* RXJAVA RXANDROID */
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.11'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'

}
```

**Create Request :**

```
interface ApiService {

    @POST("get-data")
    fun getData(@Body parameter : CustomParameter): Single<Response<CustomObject>>

    companion object {

        private val rxJava3CallAdapterFactory: RxJava3CallAdapterFactory
            get() = RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io())

        private fun okHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
            val okHttpClientBuilder = okHttpClientBuilder()

            okHttpClientBuilder.addNetworkInterceptor { chain ->
                val request = chain.request()
                val response = chain.proceed(request)
                if (response.code >= 400) {
                    handleNetworkError()
                }
                response
            }

            okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor { chain ->
                val request = chain.request()
                chain.proceed(request)
            }

            return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
        }

        fun createApiService(context: Context): ApiService {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJava3CallAdapterFactory)
                    .client(okHttpClient())
                    .build()

            return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

**Call Request (In Activity):**

```
    ApiService.createMainWeatherApiService().getData(CustomParameter())
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(
                      { res ->
                          handleSuccess()
                      },
                      { error ->
                          // UnknownHostException!!!!
                          handleFail()
                      }
              ).apply { compositeDisposable.add(this) }
```

I created an issue on okhttp : https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6591

Comment: If an error occurs on a phone. Does switching to WiFi or 4G works without reinstalling or closing app?  try 2 3 different WiFi on the same phone..!

Comment: I had experienced a similar issue which was Godaddy SSL problem. switching to amazon ssl solved the problem.  But in my scenario switching to WiFi sometimes worked. I tested 3 4 WiFi.

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli I'll try by changing the domain, Thanks for advices

Comment: I changed from Godaddy to another company, but experiencing the same symptoms.

Comment: Hmm it looks like I have the same problem. 2 users on samsung android 11 reported similar issue that for a week all requests in app are unsuccessfully with internet connection error. App reinstalling helped.

Comment: @hanmolee have you found the solution of this issue? I am also facing the same issue with Samsung 11 device on mobile data. Everything is working fine with WiFi.

Comment: @hanmolee Any findings? I am still facing this issue.

Comment: @hanmolee have you found the solution for it? I face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you include output from an event listener which will show the DNS calls that OkHttp makes (typically) using the system DNS provider?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66398516/1542667

```
[0 ms] callStart: Request{method=GET, url=https://httpbin.org/get}
[11 ms] proxySelectStart: https://httpbin.org/
[12 ms] proxySelectEnd: [DIRECT]
[12 ms] dnsStart: httpbin.org
[55 ms] dnsEnd: [httpbin.org/54.147.165.197, httpbin.org/34.231.30.52, httpbin.org/54.91.118.50, httpbin.org/18.214.80.1, httpbin.org/54.166.163.67, httpbin.org/34.199.75.4]
[62 ms] connectStart: httpbin.org/54.147.165.197:443 DIRECT
[176 ms] secureConnectStart
[747 ms] secureConnectEnd: Handshake{tlsVersion=TLS_1_2 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 peerCertificates=[CN=httpbin.org, CN=Amazon, OU=Server CA 1B, O=Amazon, C=US, CN=Amazon Root CA 1, O=Amazon, C=US] localCertificates=[]}
[765 ms] connectEnd: h2
[767 ms] connectionAcquired: Connection{httpbin.org:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=httpbin.org/54.147.165.197:443 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=h2}
[775 ms] requestHeadersStart
[783 ms] requestHeadersEnd
[993 ms] responseHeadersStart
[994 ms] responseHeadersEnd: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://httpbin.org/get}
[999 ms] responseBodyStart
[999 ms] responseBodyEnd: byteCount=267
[999 ms] connectionReleased
[1000 ms] callEnd
```

A second request may skip this, see below, to reuse a connection.  But in your case you are expecting it to make a new DNS request before establishing a new connection.

```
[0 ms] callStart: Request{method=GET, url=https://httpbin.org/get}
[1 ms] connectionAcquired: Connection{httpbin.org:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=httpbin.org/54.147.165.197:443 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=h2}
[1 ms] requestHeadersStart
[1 ms] requestHeadersEnd
[98 ms] responseHeadersStart
[99 ms] responseHeadersEnd: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://httpbin.org/get}
[99 ms] responseBodyStart
[99 ms] responseBodyEnd: byteCount=267
[99 ms] connectionReleased
[99 ms] callEnd
```

If it shows you making queries on each call, then it's likely that you would see the same behaviour just calling `InetAddress.getAllByName(hostname).toList()` multiple times in your program.  What would you expect that to show?

Comment: I did what I told you, but I am working to change the DNS every time like the first one. This is an important reason for not finding DNS?

Comment: You are asking this as an OkHttp question (tagged along with retrofit, android, galaxy).  The first thing that would help me understand is whether you are really making a DNS call on each request. It's quite likely all that is happening is that eventually multiple calls to `InetAddress.getAllByName(hostname).toList()` inside Dns.SYSTEM are returning the same results.

Is there something about these Samsung phones that mean they are caching DNS results?

Comment: the result of InetAddress.getAllByName(hostname).toList() is [hostName/2206:~~, hostName/2206:~~, hostName/~~, hostName/~~] My hostname is coming out normally. Symptoms only occur in some Samsung & Android 11 users. It seems like a Samsung device problem. – hanmolee 2 days ago    Delete

Answer (score -3):

Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.
[Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/UnknownHostException)
I hope this URL will help you: [UnknownHostException Soultion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793975/retrofit-java-net-unknownhostexception-but-the-url-is-valid)

Comment: The question isn't about what an `UnknownHostException` is; it's _why_ is it consistently happening to specific apps, largely on Samsung devices running Android 11 and _why_ does rebooting the device solve the problem? Is there anything an app developer can do to mitigate this issue affecting thousands of users, without expecting them to perform extra steps?

Comment: (if rebooting the device then solve the problem). it might be on the device problem. because some of the devices are internet sometimes unstable. (i have one that type of device)

Comment: Except that no other applications on the device seem to be affected at the same time (as in, they experience no network connectivity issues). This also didn't start occurring for us until an update to OkHttp 4.9.1 (from 3.12.12), suggesting that there is _something_ that could be done

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but those suggestions are a bit off-target. If we cannot replicate the issue, logging the response body (which won't exist anyway, given the symptoms) won't help. The API URL is also irrelevant to the problem, given that it works on a system reboot